# Image linking when working in dev, beta and prod environments

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, dom

It's very hard to put a title to this problem but it's a simple problem really.  I have a situation where I need to change the inner html of an element with an image in it.

```
 if(idExists != true)
    { var int_eventid = parseInt(eventid);
        ids.push(int_eventid);
        console.log(ids.length + cartCount);
        if(ids.length == 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("fakeCount").innerHTML = '<span style="background-color: #e9edf0; padding: 10px; border-radius: 15px; width: 100%;"><img style = "height: 20px; width: 20px;" src="' + 'http://hidden.com/assets/images/cart_img.jpg' + '"> <span style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; background-color: #5583ff; color: white; border-radius: 100%; font-size: 10px;">' + ids.length + '</span></span></a>';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("fakeCount").innerHTML = '<span style="background-color: #e9edf0; padding: 10px; border-radius: 15px; width: 100%;"><img style = "height: 20px; width: 20px;" src="' + 'http://hidden.com/assets/images/cart_img.jpg' + '"> <span style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; background-color: #5583ff; color: white; border-radius: 100%; font-size: 10px;">' + ids.length + '</span></span></a>';

        }
    }
    else{
        //do noting and it won't be clickable
    }
```

The problem Is I want my code for all three environments to be the same, but obviously I have to change the domain name for each situation in this case.  My framework is codeigniter and I have three environments dev, beta and prod.  The problem is solved in php codeigniter by:

```
<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/myimage.jpg'); ?>
```

But in JavaScript I cannot put php and I do not want to hard code in "hidden-dev.com/assests..." then "hidden-beta.com/assets..." etc..

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: why not use a relative path? that works if the directory structure is the same in all 3 versions

Comment: this: ../assets/images/img.jpg  did not work but simply /assets/images/img.jpg did work.  Duh!  I feel dumb haha.  But you helped me figure it out thanks!